# excel byrow with match value that is an array in a data table

Tags: datatable, match, excel-365

I have a 2D table of timeseries data. I am able to use the following equation in column B:
"**=BYROW(Value_Array,LAMBDA(x,MIN(x)))**" to get the minimum value for each row that results in an array output. In column C the following **does not** work "**=BYROW(Value_Array,LAMBDA(x,MATCH(B6#,x,0)))**" to find the column (time period) where the minimum value happened and results in a spilled array.

I very much like the array results because the data table size is always changing, and it is easier to let excel automatically adjust to the correct size as needed. I am sharing with others of varying abilities so VBA is a no-no.

Is there an excel formula that can match column with the minimum value for each row of the table and results in a spilled range output?

I tried using B6# (spilled array) in the match function in column C per the following: **=BYROW(Value_Array,LAMBDA(x,MATCH(B6#,x,0)))** and expecting a spilled array but get a **#CALC!** error. If I replace B6# with just B6, the results are a spilled array with only the first row resulting in the correct value and remaining rows with **#N/A** errors.